# Creating HK2 modules

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, glassfish, osgi

I'm trying to leverage the [Hundred Kilobyte Kernel (HK2)](http://hk2.java.net/) framework, however I can't find any tutorials or working examples of it. I have installed Maven, as it is required, but I can't find the archetypes to work with. I'm working with Eclipse, and I have only found this [Netbeans guide](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HK2) but even the example source files are non existent.

Under Eclipse, I managed to install the [m2e maven plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) and I have tried to start a new project, however when I try to search for the hk2 archetype to create my customization of it I can't find the required resources. I try to create a new project, and then add an archetype, I specify com.sun.enterprise as the group id, the artifact id as hk2 (and hk2-maven-plugin as per some instructions), the latest version I could find (1.6.9) and the remote location as http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/, but even when the [jar files](http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/com/sun/enterprise/hk2/1.6.9/) are there, there is no archetype catalog file that I can find. I have also tried adding this location as a Remote Catalog, but since there is no xml file to point to, it says the catalog is empty.

My question is, does anyone have any updated resources or startup steps to create an hk2 module? or can tell me how to use what I have? Inside the jars there are pom.xml files, however if I import those to Eclipse, it has errors that I don't know how to fix. Development on the project seems almost completely halted (last updates are from jul 2011) but maybe someone already familiar with Glassfish plugin development can point me in the right direction? or maybe could someone recommend an alternative to HK2? If anyone has any good OSGi tutorials that would be nice too, or any other similar framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're better off with OSGi ... The HK2 (which would surprise me if it was still 100k) was an attempt to not depend on OSGi directly for Glassfish. I do not think it has a well maintained API.

Since OSGi is a well defined and maintained API, that it runs on Glassfish, and that you also get portability to other environments seems to indicate that the choice for OSGi is smarter. The easiest way to get started is http://bndtools.org/

Comment: Yeah, already evaluated that option, but I believe the scope of the idea was narrowed down such that probably only a dependency injection framework would be needed. Options I'm considering are Guice or Butterfly Container. OSGi was deemed to complex at the moment. Maybe we'll go back for a second review.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do Glassfish module development I can recommend you following tutorials and one example taken from the Glassfish trunk. Just have a look there how they do it. I tried it once, but since HK2 is not really OSGi as Peter already mentioned, I let it be after some time :) But maybe you can take advantages of these information now ;)

- http://kalali.me/glassfish-modularity-system-how-extend-glassfish-cli-and-web-administration-console-part-2-developing-sample-modules/
- http://java.net/projects/glassfish-samples/sources/svn/show/trunk/v3/plugin/adminconsole/console-sample-ip/

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It's not really a Glassfish module, I'm just trying to leverage some HK2 functionality and use it as a dependency injection framework. It seems Guice and Butterfly Container might be better options as HK2 seems basically dead.